# Bootstrap not optimizing website for cell phones?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, optimization

http://www.razaprinters.com/bootstrap.html

Hi I have made this page using bootstrap it is working fine on Desktops i am mostly using classes like col-xs-4 or 12 but when i open my website on a cellphone it is not optimizing things are behaving awkwardly like the about us divs goes all the way up and etc. any help with the code will be helpful i am not posting the code as you can go to inspect element or view source code to access it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Read up. We are not going to go to external sites trying to debug what's wrong with something. Rather post the code here.

Comment: I was 20 years old then didn't know about so many things, this is so stupid question which i asked :( back then

Answer (score 1):

In order for bootstrap to "work" you should put your columns inside container and row classes.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more information go here [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Container is a parent to content you want to style, it can have multiple rows inside. A row is sort of horizontal group (like a row in a table). Rows have 12 columns, but you can apply different widths to elements to target different views (dektop, mobile) depending on screen width. You need a row element if you want columns to work. For instance if you use:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then this will take 50% width (it will be on the left) of parent .container element on larger screens and 100% width of parent .container on smaller screens. Hope that clarifies something. I really recommend reading Bootstrap documentation - it's short and simple.

Comment: can you tell me how does row work like if i want to display it in particular place and dont want it to go anywhere then i should use row ? does rows have sizes like col ?